# How to upload image from PhoneGap to Asp.Net Web API?

Tags: c#, cordova, mime-types, file-transfer

I have these available APIs:

```
[HttpPost]
[CorsEnabled]
[ActionName("upstream")]
public DTO.Callback UploadPhoto(Stream data)
{
    var m = new Logic.Components.User();
    return m.UploadPhoto(data, Common.UserValues().Email);
}

[HttpPost]
[CorsEnabled]
[ActionName("upbyte")]
public DTO.Callback UploadPhoto(byte[] data)
{
    var m = new Logic.Components.User();
    return m.UploadPhoto(data, Common.UserValues().Email);
}

[HttpPost]
[CorsEnabled]
[ActionName("upfile")]
public DTO.Callback UploadPhoto(HttpPostedFileBase data)
{
    var m = new Logic.Components.User();
    return m.UploadPhoto(data, Common.UserValues().Email);
}

[HttpPost]
[CorsEnabled]
[ActionName("up")]
public DTO.Callback UploadPhoto(DTO.UserPhoto data)
{
    var m = new Logic.Components.User();
    return m.UploadPhoto(data, Common.UserValues().Email);
}
```

`UserPhoto` class

```
public class UserPhoto
{
    public string Base64 { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

In the behind code, I try to convert or get the equivalent byte[] of each request data.
If I would get the correct Image byte, then I'm good to go.

In my PhoneGap application, I have these codes:

A function that opens the camera:

```
takePicture: function (success, error) {
    var s = function (data) {
            navigator.camera.cleanup();
            (success || angular.noop)(data);
        },
        e = function (data) {
            navigator.camera.cleanup();
            (error || angular.noop)(data);
        };

    navigator.camera.getPicture(s, e,
        {
            quality: 100,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
            correctOrientation: true
        }
    );
}
```

My first try is to convert the image to base64 string and use the 'up' API.
It works just fine for low `quality` not higher than `50`. But the image becomes almost unrecognizable. So I set the `quality` to `100`. And then the new problem comes, the phone hangs...

So I tried to use `FileTransfer`. Here is the code:

```
fileTransfer: function (filePath, serverUri, mimeType, params, success, error) {
    var
        u = $coreData.user.getSession()
        ;

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = 'file';
    options.mimeType = mimeType;
    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = true;
    options.headers = {
        Connection: 'close',
        Device: m.createDeviceHeader(),
        'Authentication-Token': (u && u.SessionKey),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(filePath, encodeURI(serverUri), success, error, options);
}
```

Sample usage:

```
uploadFile: function (path) {
    var def = $q.defer();
    $coreUtility
        .fileTransfer(path, $coreAPI.user.getUrl('upfile'), 'image/png', null,
        function (success) {


            def.resolve(m.callback(true, UPLOAD_PHOTO_SUCCESS, success));
        },
        function (error) {


            def.reject(m.callback(false, UPLOAD_PHOTO_FAIL, error));
        });
    return def.promise;
}
```

But I was not able to upload the file, I always get not supported media type formatter and sometimes null reference exceptions. I'm totally out of idea.

Answer (score 2):

Alright I get it now. For other struggling on the same problem, here is the solution.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [CorsEnabled]
    [ActionName("upfile")]
    public DTO.Callback UploadPhoto()
    {
        var m = new Logic.Components.User();
        return m.UploadPhoto(HttpContext.Current.Request, Common.UserValues().Email);
    }
```

Some logic:

```
    public DTO.Callback UploadPhoto(HttpRequest req, string email)
    {
        if (req.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var file = req.Files[0];
            var m = new Logic.Components.User();
            return m.UploadPhoto(file.InputStream, email);
        }

        return new DTO.Callback { Message = "Fail to upload. Make sure that you are uploading an image file." };
    }
```

Some explanation about the solution:

The first part is your API, and the second part is the backend code.

To pass the image stream from `PhoneGap` to your `ASP.Net MVC Web API`, you will just have to use `HttpContext.Current.Request` to get the `Stream` from Phonegap.